# Does $\{f_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ have a convergent subsequence in $L^2((0, 1))$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\{f_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subset C^1([0, 1])$ be such that $f_n(0) = 0$ and $$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left\| {d\over{dx}}f_n\right\|_2 < \infty.$$Does $\{f_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ have a convergent subsequence in $L^2((0, 1))$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let

$$\sup_{n\in \mathbb N} \| f'_n\|_2 = D <\infty.$$

Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, if $f = f_n$,

$$|f(x)| = |f(x) - f(0)| = \left|\int_0^x f'(s) ds \right| \le \sqrt x \|f'\|_2 \le D.$$

So $\{f_n\}$ has a uniform $C^0$ bound. Similarly,

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le \sqrt{|x-y|} \|f'\|_2 \le \sqrt{|x-y|}D.$$

Thus the family $\{f_n\}$ is equi-continuous and so has a $C^0$ (Not only $L^2$) convergent subsequence, by the Ascoli-Arzela theorem.